# Comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pgm.c"

void umbral(char **Original, char **Salida) {
    int x,y;
    for(x=0;x<Largo;x++) {
        for(y=0;y<Alto;y++) {
            if (Original[x][y] <= umbral) {
                Salida[x][y]=0;
            } else {
                Salida[x][y] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **Original = (char **)pgmread(argv[1], &Largo, &Alto);
    char **Salida = (char **)Matriz(Largo, Alto, sizeof(char));

    umbral(Original, Salida);
    pgmwrite(Salida, "umbral.pgm", Largo, Alto);
}
```

Me da el siguiente error:

> Warning: Comparison between pointer and integer on line 10 | if(Original[x][y] <= umbral

Alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void umbral(char **Original, char **Salida) {
    int x,y;
    for(x=0;x<Largo;x++) {
        for(y=0;y<Alto;y++) {
            if (Original[x][y] <= umbral) {
                Salida[x][y]=0;
            } else {
                Salida[x][y] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Original` es un array de punteros dobles, luego `Original[x][y]` es un entero. Sin embargo `umbral` es la propia función.

¿Cómo se compara una función con un entero?

Necesitas declarar una variable que te haga de umbral en algún sitio. No se, si el umbral es fijo podría ser una macro:

```
#define UMBRAL 20

void umbral(char **Original, char **Salida) {
    int x,y;
    for(x=0;x<Largo;x++) {
        for(y=0;y<Alto;y++) {
            if (Original[x][y] <= UMBRAL) {
                Salida[x][y]=0;
            } else {
                Salida[x][y] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O, si puede variar con el tiempo (y no quieres modificar la llamada a la función `umbral`:

```
int limite = 20;

void umbral(char **Original, char **Salida) {
    int x,y;
    for(x=0;x<Largo;x++) {
        for(y=0;y<Alto;y++) {
            if (Original[x][y] <= limite) {
                Salida[x][y]=0;
            } else {
                Salida[x][y] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
}
```